# Loading a .class file into a jar?

Tags: java, class, jar, zip

Is it possible to do any of the following?:

1. Create a new JAR file from a given .class file?
2. Insert a local .class file into an existing JAR?

It seems that I would need to somehow read the .class into a `JarEntry`, but this does not seem possible with any of the existing `JarEntry` constructors. Is there any workaround or alternative ways of accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Looking for a programming solution

Comment: you want to do this manually or write a program for the same?

Answer (score 3):

jar files are just zip files with classes in it. When you have java installed on your machine you can create jar files the **jar** command.

If you use a java IDE it should have a option to create a jar file from some classes.

But most people use a build tool to accomplish that. Well known and widely used java build tools are [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Apache Ant is probably better to start with if you're new to java and it's tooling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry for being unclear, but I'm looking for a way to do it in java code; presumable using a JarOutputStream somehow by getting a JarEntry from the classfile

Answer (score 0):

Using .class files you can extract the source code using [JAD decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29). Then create a new JAR file of your own where you modify as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some utility methods to add files to ZIP/JAR files using the NIO2 File API (the library is Open Source):

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

API: [CopyFileVisitor.copy](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)